# Create a android library with intents in it

Tags: android

Where can I find a guide or a sample for creating a library that expose intents, and compiled as a jar?

I find it very hard to achieve this simple capability and don't understand why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where can I find a guide or a sample for creating a library that expose intents, and compiled as a jar?

That is not presently possible.

You are welcome to create an Android JAR, but it cannot on its own "expose intents" for any likely translation of the phrase "expose intents".

If the JAR contains activities, services, receivers, and providers, those have to be registered in the manifest of the project that is incorporating that JAR.

If your code that you would like to have in the JAR needs resources, then you cannot package the code as a JAR, but instead would need to use an Android library project. Once again, any components (e.g., activities) defined in the library have to be registered in the manifest of the project that is incorporating the library.